# Python tkinter error, self.master

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

1. I have written code below. It shows error.
   Code & error are below.
2. What does this statement mean:
   `self.master=master`
   How does it work i.e assigning same varible name `master` to `master` again?
3. What is best place to start learning `tkinter`.

   ```
   from Tkinter import *
   import Tkinter


   class menu1():

       def __init__(self, master):
           self.master = master 

           #clear value
           self.val1 = 1

           #default selection
           self.v = IntVar()
           self.v.set(1)

           #create a label
           self.x1 = Label(self, text="Title", justify=CENTER, padx=100)
           self.x1.pack()

           #first radiobutton
           self.x2 = Radiobutton(self, text="Title1", padx=100, variable=self.v, value=1)
           self.x2.pack(anchor=W)

           #create button
           self.x6 = Button(self,text="OK",command=self.submit)     
           self.x6.pack()

       def submit(self):
           self.val1 = self.v.get()
           self.destroy()

       def suicide(self):
           self.val1 = 0
           self.destroy()        

   def screen():
       #create a root object
       root = Tk()
       app = menu1(root)
       app.title("Option")
       app.geometry("480x320")
       app.mainloop()
       return app.val1

   screen();
   ```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/abc/Desktop/c.py", line 47, in <module>
    app = menu1(root)
  File "C:/Users/abc/Desktop/c.py", line 19, in __init__
    screen();
  File "C:/Users/abc/Desktop/c.py", line 41, in screen
    self.x1 = Label(self,text="Title",justify = CENTER,padx = 100)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2591, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2081, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2059, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: menu1 instance has no attribute 'tk'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Code & error are below.
>   ...
>   AttributeError: menu1 instance has no attribute 'tk'

The problem is with lines like this:

```
self.x1 = Label(self,...)
self.x2 = Radiobutton(self,...)
self.x6 = Button(self,...)
```

The first parameter when creating a widget must be a reference to another widget. You're passing `self` which is not a widget. In the way you've written your code you should be passing `self.master` as the first argument.

> What does this statement mean: self.master=master

Prior to that line, `master` is a local variable that was passed in. This statement is creating an instance attribute that contains the same value as the local variable. This saves the value of `master` and makes it available to every method in your class.

> What is best place to start learning tkinter.

Asking for "the best", or for pointers to tutorials or reference material if off topic for stackoverflow. There are many tutorials and books on tkinter. Search for "tkinter tutorial" on google, you'll find links to many.